# Can I forward/mapping remote /dev/gpiomem to local

Tags: gpio, ssh

I want to write code in my laptop by just using gpiomem to control the GPIO, is it possible to bring /dev/gpiomem to local, just like sshfs dose ?

**EDIT**

I want to use [go-rpio](https://github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio) to control the GPIO, it require `/dev/gpiomem` or `/dev/mem` and `/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges`.

I want to map these device/file to my laptop, so I can run the program from my laptop, it's why better than using sshfs mount pi's folder to local edit and run from pi.

Current I use sshfs like this

```
sshfs -o sshfs_sync,sync_readdir,reconnect,follow_symlinks root@pi:/ pi
```

`/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges` is accessible, but

```
$ head pi/dev/gpiomem
head: error reading 'pi/dev/gpiomem': Operation not permitted
$ head pi/dev/mem
head: error reading 'pi/dev/mem': Operation not permitted
```

so, is there any way to map pi's `/dev/mem` or `/dev/gpio` to local ?

Answer (score 1):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) lets you control the GPIO of one or more Pis from your laptop.

Your Python script talks over the network to the [pigpio daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) which needs to be running on the Pis. You can write C programs as well if your laptop is Linux.

The pigpio daemon uses /dev/mem rather than /dev/gpiomem (it allows access to more than just the GPIO).

Alternatively you could just launch a command on the Pi with ssh.

`ssh pi@raspberry command`

Comment: I try to use [go-rpio](https://github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio) from my Mac, currently I sshfs code to edit from my laptop, go-rpio need gpiomem or mem and ranges, ranges is ok, but gpiomem and mem are not permitted from sshfs.

Comment: @wener I suggest that information is important enough to be edited into your question as it may affect the answers you get.